# Checkbox tree view with nesting parent and child both.?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to create tree view of multiple checkbox as tree everything working fine I just not being able to achieve goal to when child checkbox been check let its parent checkbox also checked. I find example from

http://experiments.wemakesites.net/css3-treeview-with-multiple-node-selection.html

```
 <div class="form-group form-show-validation row">
    <label for="name" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 mt-sm-2 text-right">Permissions <span class="required-label">*</span></label>
    <div class="acidjs-css3-treeview col-lg-4 col-md-9 col-sm-8">
        <ul>
            <li>
                
                <input type="checkbox" id="node-0" checked="checked" /><label><input type="checkbox" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0">Libraries</label>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="node-0-0" checked="checked" /><label><input type="checkbox" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-0">Documents</label>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="node-0-0-0" checked="checked" /><label><input type="checkbox" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-0-0">My Documents</label>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="node-0-0-0-0" /><label><input type="checkbox" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-0-0-0">Downloads</label>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="node-0-0-0-1" /><label><input type="checkbox" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-0-0-1">Projects</label>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="node-0-1" /><label><input type="checkbox" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-1">Music</label>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="node-0-1-0" /><label><input type="checkbox" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-1-0">My Music</label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="node-0-1-1" /><label><input type="checkbox" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-1-1">Public Music</label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="node-0-2" /><label><input type="checkbox" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-2">Pictures</label>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="node-0-2-0" /><label><input type="checkbox" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-2-0">My Pictures</label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="node-0-2-1" /><label><input type="checkbox" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-2-1">Public Pictures</label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="node-0-3" checked="checked" /><label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-3">Video</label>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="node-0-3-0" /><label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-3-0">My Videos</label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="node-0-3-1" /><label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-3-1">Public Videos</label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is javascript code which will be required

```
  <script>
    $(".acidjs-css3-treeview").delegate("label input:checkbox", "change", function() {
var
    checkbox = $(this),
    nestedList = checkbox.parent().next().next(),
    nestedListp = checkbox.parent().prev().prev(),
    selectNestedListCheckbox = nestedList.find("label:not([for]) input:checkbox");
    selectNestedListCheckboxp = nestedListp.find("label:not([for]) input:checkbox");

if(checkbox.is(":checked")) {
    return selectNestedListCheckbox.prop("checked", true);
    return selectNestedListCheckboxp.prop("checked", true);
  }
   selectNestedListCheckbox.prop("checked", false);
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is working demo by [Fabien](https://codepen.io/fsbdev/pen/nILhu)

```js
$(function() {

  $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(checkboxChanged);

  function checkboxChanged() {
    var $this = $(this),
        checked = $this.prop("checked"),
        container = $this.parent(),
        siblings = container.siblings();

    container.find('input[type="checkbox"]')
    .prop({
        indeterminate: false,
        checked: checked
    })
    .siblings('label')
    .removeClass('custom-checked custom-unchecked custom-indeterminate')
    .addClass(checked ? 'custom-checked' : 'custom-unchecked');

    checkSiblings(container, checked);
  }

  function checkSiblings($el, checked) {
    var parent = $el.parent().parent(),
        all = true,
        indeterminate = false;

    $el.siblings().each(function() {
      return all = ($(this).children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked") === checked);
    });

    if (all && checked) {
      parent.children('input[type="checkbox"]')
      .prop({
          indeterminate: false,
          checked: checked
      })
      .siblings('label')
      .removeClass('custom-checked custom-unchecked custom-indeterminate')
      .addClass(checked ? 'custom-checked' : 'custom-unchecked');

      checkSiblings(parent, checked);
    } 
    else if (all && !checked) {
      indeterminate = parent.find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0;

      parent.children('input[type="checkbox"]')
      .prop("checked", checked)
      .prop("indeterminate", indeterminate)
      .siblings('label')
      .removeClass('custom-checked custom-unchecked custom-indeterminate')
      .addClass(indeterminate ? 'custom-indeterminate' : (checked ? 'custom-checked' : 'custom-unchecked'));

      checkSiblings(parent, checked);
    } 
    else {
      $el.parents("li").children('input[type="checkbox"]')
      .prop({
          indeterminate: true,
          checked: false
      })
      .siblings('label')
      .removeClass('custom-checked custom-unchecked custom-indeterminate')
      .addClass('custom-indeterminate');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

#page-wrap {
  margin: auto 0;
}

.treeview {
  margin: 10px 0 0 20px;
}

ul { 
  list-style: none;
}

.treeview li {
  background: url(http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/images/treeview-default-line.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;
  padding: 2px 0 2px 16px;
}

.treeview > li:first-child > label {
  /* style for the root element - IE8 supports :first-child
  but not :last-child ..... */
  
}

.treeview li.last {
  background-position: 0 -1766px;
}

.treeview li > input {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  /* hide the inputs but keep them in the layout with events (use opacity) */
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* internet explorer */ 
  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0)"; /*IE8*/
}

.treeview li > label {
  background: url(https://www.thecssninja.com/demo/css_custom-forms/gr_custom-inputs.png) 0 -1px no-repeat;
  /* move left to cover the original checkbox area */
  margin-left: -20px;
  /* pad the text to make room for image */
  padding-left: 20px;
}

/* Unchecked styles */

.treeview .custom-unchecked {
  background-position: 0 -1px;
}
.treeview .custom-unchecked:hover {
  background-position: 0 -21px;
}

/* Checked styles */

.treeview .custom-checked { 
  background-position: 0 -81px;
}
.treeview .custom-checked:hover { 
  background-position: 0 -101px; 
}

/* Indeterminate styles */

.treeview .custom-indeterminate { 
  background-position: 0 -141px; 
}
.treeview .custom-indeterminate:hover { 
  background-position: 0 -121px; 
}
```

```html
    <div id="page-wrap">
    
       <h2>Treeview with Custom Checkboxes and Indeterminate State</h2>
        
     <ul class="treeview">
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="tall" id="tall">
            <label for="tall" class="custom-unchecked">Tall Things</label>
            
            <ul>
                 <li>
                     <input type="checkbox" name="tall-1" id="tall-1">
                     <label for="tall-1" class="custom-unchecked">Buildings</label>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                     <input type="checkbox" name="tall-2" id="tall-2">
                     <label for="tall-2" class="custom-unchecked">Giants</label>
                     <ul>
                         <li>
                             <input type="checkbox" name="tall-2-1" id="tall-2-1">
                             <label for="tall-2-1" class="custom-unchecked">Andre</label>
                         </li>
                         <li class="last">
                             <input type="checkbox" name="tall-2-2" id="tall-2-2">
                             <label for="tall-2-2" class="custom-unchecked">Paul Bunyan</label>
                         </li>
                     </ul>
                 </li>
                 <li class="last">
                     <input type="checkbox" name="tall-3" id="tall-3">
                     <label for="tall-3" class="custom-unchecked">Two sandwiches</label>
                 </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="last">
            <input type="checkbox" name="short" id="short">
            <label for="short" class="custom-unchecked">Short Things</label>
            
            <ul>
                 <li>
                     <input type="checkbox" name="short-1" id="short-1">
                     <label for="short-1" class="custom-unchecked">Smurfs</label>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                     <input type="checkbox" name="short-2" id="short-2">
                     <label for="short-2" class="custom-unchecked">Mushrooms</label>
                 </li>
                 <li class="last">
                     <input type="checkbox" name="short-3" id="short-3">
                     <label for="short-3" class="custom-unchecked">One Sandwich</label>
                 </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    
    </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since my first answer below, I have developed a [Hybrid HTML Dropdown](https://aurovrata.github.io/hybrid-html-dropdown/) plugin to solve the general case problem of checked lists and nested lists as well as the option to create thumbnail based check lists [fields](https://aurovrata.github.io/hybrid-html-dropdown/examples/#image-grid-no-dropdown).  So the above problem can now be solved with the following html/js,

```js
function docReady(fn) {
  if (document.readyState!='loading'){
    fn();
  }else if (document.addEventListener){
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
  }
}
docReady( (e)=>{
  let sel= document.querySelector('#nested-list');
  let hyd = new HybridDropdown(sel,{});
});
```

```html
<link href="https://aurovrata.github.io/hybrid-html-dropdown/assets/css/hybrid-dropdown.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://aurovrata.github.io/hybrid-html-dropdown/assets/js/hybrid-dropdown.js"></script>


<div id="nested-list" data-tree-view="true" data-color="#ff26ffc9"
data-background-color="#454d4f">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "":"Select a dish",
      "Japan":{
        "sushi":{
          "label":"Sushi",
          "ps":"Pumpkin sushi",
          "as":"Avocado sushi",
          "tc":"Tomato sushi",
          "cs":"Carrot sushi"
        }
      },
      "India":{
        "dosa":{
          "label":"Dosa",
          "pd":"Plain dosa",
          "md":"Masala dosa",
          "myd":"Mysore dosa",
          "pr":"Paper roast"
        }
      }
    }
   </script>
</div>
```